# Level 9 compression in R

Tags: php, r, compression, gzip

I am making a POST call for that I have to do a compression 
below is my php code which is doing compress perfectly fine

```
 $msg = base64_encode(gzcompress($msg,9))
```

I want to do same level 9 commpresion in R language. I tried "xz","gzip" and "bzip2"

```
 y2 <- memCompress(x, "bzip2")
 y3 <- memCompress(x, "xz")
```

but these 2 are also not giving me the same string as PHP code.
Please help

Comment: I don't know anything about R's compression but there are a number of slightly different ways to do gzip compression in PHP: `gzdeflate()`, `gzencode()`, `gzcompress()`. Note that each function also takes a third argument for encoding mode, so you've probably got six or so different combinations you can try.

Comment: Are you sure it has to be the same string? Different compressed bytes may very well expand to the same uncompressed string. Are you sure the compression level is the problem with your POST?

Comment: @MrFlick I am doing these 3 steps before the POST call

1.request_body_json <- toJSON(request_body, auto_unbox = TRUE)
2.param1 <-base64_enc(memCompress(request_body_json, "xz"))
3.param2 <- digest::hmac('Secret Key', object = param1, algo = 'sha256', serialize = TRUE)
I am getting different Param1 and Param2 value from PHP code and from R code. My Php code is giving correct result but R code is not giving correct result.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you care that the compressed result be the same? All that matters is that after decompression you get what you started with. You should just check for that.

There is no guarantee that you will get the same compressed output from any given compressor, unless it is exactly the same implementation, with exactly the same version, and with all of the same settings (e.g. compression levels, memory used, etc.) Compressors can generate many possible outputs for the same input, and all of those outputs are valid since when decompressed they all give the same original input.